# Is "be set to" a subject-to-subject raising predicate?

Tags: syntax, verbs, control, raising

Consider the sentence "Conservative Party (is) Set to Win (a) Majority".

Is it right that "set" in this case is a subject-to-subject raising? I don't think "set" has an agent theta role. However, all tests show that it should be control: "be set to" does not admit expletives, and the meaning of idioms seems not to  be preserved. (But I'm not a native speaker, so I may be mistaken on this.)

Comment: Yes, it means _is expected to_, and that takes [A-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) with passive: _The Tories are expected to win a majority_ (It takes B-Raising without passive: _They expect the Tories to win a majority_). Of course, this is headline syntax, with all the bells and whistles removed.

Comment: @jlawler How come that this raising verb does not pass tests for raising verbs? Carnie mentions two tests: (1) you should be able to insert expletives; (2) idiomatic meaning should be preserved.  (1) doesn't seem to work here: *It is set that ... -- you can't say that. (2) The cat is set to be out of the bag. -- Does this still have idiomatic reading?

Comment: Another idiom-part test is ??"The shit is set to hit the fan," which I find to be quite odd-sounding.

Comment: As I said, it's headlinese, quite a restricted context.

Comment: @jlawler I'm not sure I understand why being headlinese or having restricted context matters here. Are headline-type raising predicates "allowed" to not pass tests for raising predicates? This expression can be used in non-headline contexts as well; this wouldn't change the raising nature, but it still wouldn't be able to pass tests for raising predicate.

Comment: Yes, the adjective "set" takes a raised subject: it belongs semantically in the infinitival clause.